# Ionic Android build failing using Jenkins

Tags: android, macos, jenkins, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a CI/CD flow using Jenkins to build and hopefully deploy the Android app after. I have Jenkins using the script to inject the node dependencies and start to use ionic cli commands.

I'm having an issue though that Jenkins isn't seeing my ANDROID path. I do indeed have it set up as I can run the android command in my terminal. Am I doing something wrong with my commands below?

```
source /etc/profile
npm install # Really important (it installs all your project 
dependencies)
ionic cordova build android
```

ERROR:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' 
environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' 
to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

Any help would be great as I'm trying to upskill but I can't find much material online for this.

=========================================================================

I was able to fix this! But I'm having another issue now :/

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 
'/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/source.properties'
```

I made jenkins a user with sudo privileges and even made the file read and writable to everyone. Has anyone been able to allow Jenkins to have full access to everything to read files to run commands?

Thanks